# How to test input file with Jest and vue/test-utils

Tags: unit-testing, vuejs2, jestjs

I want to test file uploader component using Jest and vue/test-utils.

I have this:

```
 describe('show progress bar of uploading file', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(FileUploaderComponent)

    // create csv file
    let csv = new Blob([''], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' })
    csv.name = 'myFile.csv'

    let input = wrapper.find('input')
    input.element.value = csv // || csv.error value, Error here
    input.trigger('change')

    // Update current status
  })
```

Where in FileUploaderComponent i have:

```
<template>
  <form action="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" for="input-file">
      <input class="input-file" id="input-file" name="file" type="file" accept=".xlsx, .xls, .csv">
      UPLOAD FILE
    </label>
  </form>
</template>
```

Throws this error:

> InvalidStateError: This input element accepts a filename, which may
>   only be programmatically set to the empty string.

```
  49 |
  50 |     let input = wrapper.find('input')
> 51 |     input.element.value = csv
  52 |     input.trigger('change')
  53 |
  54 |     // Update current status
```

So, the question is: How can i trigger event change with file input value? in this case, a csv file as value ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this using the `DataTransfer` object. Unfortunately, it hasn't been added to JSDOM, so you can't test in Jest. There's an open issue to add the object—https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1568

If you ran your tests in a browser using Karma, you could test like this:

```js
const wrapper = shallow(FormComponent)
const input = wrapper.find('input[type="file"]')
const dT = new ClipboardEvent('').clipboardData || new DataTransfer()
dT.items.add(new File(['foo'], 'programmatically_created.txt'))
input.element.files = dT.files
await input.trigger('change')
```

Comment: any changes on this front?

Comment: same question, I don't care about testing progress, just the ability to set a file input value

Comment: Is there anything I need to import in order to use ClipboardEvent? My program throws an error that it can't find it, even though I have the npm typescript module installed.

Comment: @Anand not yet unfortunately

Comment: Use `import { DataTransfer, File } from "happy-dom"`

Comment: If you are using vitest add this comment `// @vitest-environment happy-dom` 
and it should work without needing to import manually. Make sure you have installed happy-dom as dev-dependency.

Answer (score 5):

If you're just wanting to simulate a value in `input.element.files` and changes to `input.element.value` in Jest, but not necessarily accurately simulating every DOM behavior, you can do it by defining a getter/setter for those fields. This works for me:

```
let localImageInput
let localImageInputFiles
let localImageInputValueGet
let localImageInputValueSet
let localImageInputValue = ''

beforeEach(function() {
  localImageInput = wrapper.find('#local-image-input')
  localImageInputFilesGet = jest.fn()
  localImageInputValueGet = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(localImageInputValue)
  localImageInputValueSet = jest.fn().mockImplementation(v => {
    localImageInputValue = v
  })

  Object.defineProperty(localImageInput.element, 'files', {
    get: localImageInputFilesGet
  })

  Object.defineProperty(localImageInput.element, 'value', {
    get: localImageInputValueGet,
    set: localImageInputValueSet
  })
})

it('should do the thing', function() {
  localImageInputValue = 'some-image.gif'
  localImageInputFilesGet.mockReturnValue([{
    size: 12345,
    blob: 'some-blob',
    width: 300,
    height: 200
  }])

  localImageInput.trigger('change')

  return Vue.nextTick().then(() => {
    // Assuming the component sets input.value = '' when this event is triggered
    // and calls someFn with the image data
    expect(localImageInputValue).toEqual('')
    expect(someFn.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual({
      size: 12345,
      blob: 'some-blob',
      width: 300,
      height: 200
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After many attempts I came up with a method that worked, but it may not be the best way to do this. I using the vitest with vue-test-utils

```
    const inputFile = wrapper.find('input[type="file"]') as any
    const fileMock = new File(['(file content)'], 'test-file.txt', {
        type: 'text/plain',
    })

    expect(inputFile.exists()).toBe(true)

    Object.defineProperty(inputFile.element, 'files', {
        value: [fileMock],
        writable: false,
    });      

    await inputFile.trigger('change')
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();

    expect(inputFile.element.files).toEqual([fileMock])
```