# Jest Test Case for reactive upload form for input type file <input type="file" formControlName="userslist"> (Angular 7)

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jestjs, angular-reactive-forms

I have implemented a reactive uploads form in angular 7. The form is working properly but unable to add the unit test case because `patchValue` or setValue doesn't allow us to set a dummy data in the input type file. Can anyone suggest me to write a test case in jest for input type file using reative form? I want to test `importUsers()` -

> import-users.component.html
>
> ```
> <form [formGroup]="importForm">
>     <input type="file" (change)="fileEvent($event)" name="userslist" formControlName="userslist">
> < /form>
> ```

---

> import-users.component.ts -
>
> ```
> selectedFile: any;
>
> importForm = new FormGroup({
>     userslist: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
> });
>
> fileEvent(event: any) {
>     const fileData = event.target.files;
>     this.selectedFile = fileData[0];
> }
>
> importUsers() {
>     if (this.importForm.invalid) {
>         return throwError(new Error('INVALID_FORM'));
>     }
>     const fd = new FormData();
>     fd.append('usersFile', this.selectedFile);
>
>     this.userService.importUsers({ body: fd })
>         .subscribe(() => {
>             this.closeModal();
>         });
> }
> ...
> ```

---

> import-users.component.spec.ts
>
> ```
> it('should import users', () => {
>     const file = { name: 'user.csv', type: 'text/csv' } as File;
>     jest.spyOn(userService, 'importUsers');
>     component.importForm.patchValue({
>         userslist: file,
>     });
>     component.importUsers();
>     expect(userService.importUsers).toHaveBeenCalled();
> });
> ```

Using the above test case I'm getting this bellow error message -

> InvalidStateError: This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this error by following the instructions here [How to test input file with Jest and vue/test-utils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993134/how-to-test-input-file-with-jest-and-vue-test-utils)

```
describe('fileInput',() => {
    let fileInput: HTMLElement;
    let uploadButton: HTMLElement;
    let fileInputFilesGet;
    let fileInputValueGet;
    let fileInputValueSet;
    let fileInputValue = '';

    const fileFixture: Partial<File> = {
        name: 'myimage.png', 
        lastModified: 1580400631732, 
        size: 703786, 
        type: 'image/png'
    };

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const { getByLabelText, getByText } = render (
            <FileInput/> 
        );

        fileInput = getByLabelText('File Input');
        uploadButton = getByText('UPLOAD');
        fileInputFilesGet = jest.fn();
        fileInputValueGet = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(fileFixture);
        fileInputValueSet = jest.fn().mockImplementation(v => {
          fileInputValue = v;
        });

        Object.defineProperty(fileInput, 'files', {
          get: fileInputFilesGet
        });

        Object.defineProperty(fileInput, 'value', {
          get: fileInputValueGet,
          set: fileInputValueSet
        });
    });

    it('upload file when click on upload button', async() => {
        fileInputValue = 'myimage.png';
        fileInputFilesGet.mockReturnValue([fileFixture]);

        await act(async () => {
            fireEvent.click(uploadButton);
        });

        ....
    });
```