# How to test a component can emit a file with Vue test-utils and Vitest?

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils, vitest

I want to test that my "UploadFilesComponent" enables the user to:

1. Upload a file for later use
2. Emits that file to the root component

Using Vue-Utils and vitest I came up with the test below, but receive this error:

`InvalidStateError: This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.`

How do I write the test that I can check if my component is able to receive a file via user input and emit that file to the root component?

```
describe('UploadFilesComponent', () => {
  it('can upload a picture', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(UploadFilesComponent)
    
    const file = new File(['dummy file content'], 'dummy-file.txt', { type: 'text/plain' });

    const input = wrapper.get('input[type="file"]')
    input.element.value = file
    input.trigger('change')

    expect(wrapper.emitted()).toHaveProperty('fileEmit');
  })
})
```

Comment: Check if this SA answer works. It worked for me -https://stackoverflow.com/a/49145274/5779161